# Share containers between different docker-compose

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am implementing an application composed of multiple services, where services are "independent" ASP.NET Core projects. Meaning that each service has it's own Github repository, and is developed and tested independently.

The application runs on a cluster where services are orchestrated using K8s.

Services rely on common containers/services, such as RabbitMQ and SQL Server. In production environment where all the services are orchestrated using K8s, all is fine; however, the challenge is setting up the development environment.

I want to develop/test a service without having to start the entire application. For instance, for development of `ServiceA` that depends on `RabbitMQ` and `SQL Server`, and listens to `ServiceB` events, I would like to only start `ServiceA`, `RabbitMQ`, `SQL Server` and `ServiceB`. Here is what I do:

- clone `ServiceB` repo, and use it's docker-compose to start the service. At this point, the docker compose starts `RabbitMQ` and `SQL Server`, `ServiceB` containers, and the `ServiceB` is able to publish events and persist seed data in the database.
- clone `ServiceA` repo, and use it's docker-compose to start the service. Ideally I expect the docker-compose to reuse `RabbitMQ` and `SQL Server`, and start `ServiceA` container, hence the `ServiceA` can listen to the events published using `ServiceB`.

When running docker-compose for `ServieA`, it through an error complaining that the ports (used for `RabbitMQ` and `SQL Server`) are already allocated.

Hence, I think I am missing the step where I can set the docker-compose of different services to reuse each others resources, or something like that. What is the recommended setup for such scenarios?

---

## Update 1

Some of the goals are:

- Enable running/developing *integration* tests on developers machines and CI environment, without having to replicate production environment;
- Enable developers to spin-up an environment of inter-related services to  the service they are developing.

A point to consider though is that it is not may not be pragmatic in some scenarios (including mine) to expect the developers to replicate production setup for dev purposes; because you may be using some services in production environment that are not available for developers. For instance, we're using a paid database service in the production environment, but would like to use a local/free database service in dev environment.

---

## Update 2

For faster development, we're thinking of an integration test setup where developers can test the integration between a subset of inter-related services, since running the whole application for different integration tests takes a significant amount of time (~1h), which we see it as a burden for fast development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single most important thing you need to do is to make the locations of these resources configurable.  You probably have that already, since things like the DNS name of the RabbitMQ server will be different in a local, Docker Compose, and Kubernetes environment.

In the architecture you describe you also don't really need "both" services running to do tests.  You can write a RabbitMQ setup that injects messages into a queue, and then tests that expected messages are in the output queue when you're done.  (Or mock the RabbitMQ API you're using to do the same thing.)

So for local development, you can just have a single Docker Compose YAML file that starts up RabbitMQ and the per-service SQL Server, then run your application and tests outside of Docker pointing at `localhost` and the standard port numbers for those services.

If you're trying to do integration testing on a single system, I would look at one of the single-host Kubernetes solutions (minikube, kind, ...) instead of trying to maintain duplicated deployment systems in both Kubernetes and Docker Compose.

If you really need both services running locally, you can allocate different host ports to each service's local storage, and then configure environment variables appropriately.  I'll write out `docker run` commands, but this could be translated into Docker Compose syntax too:

```sh
docker run --name rabbitmq -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3
docker run --name a-sqlserver -e ... -p 11433:1433 microsoft-mssql-server
docker run --name b-sqlserver -e ... -p 21433:1433 microsoft-mssql-server

cd service-b
env \
  RABBITMQ_HOST=localhost RABBITMQ_PORT=5672 \
  SQLSERVER_HOST=localhost SQLSERVER_PORT=21433 \
  ./service_b --port 28000

cd service-a
env \
  RABBITMQ_HOST=localhost RABBITMQ_PORT=5672 \
  SQLSERVER_HOST=localhost SQLSERVER_PORT=11433 \
  SERVICE_B_URL=http://localhost:28000 \
  ./service_a --port 18000
```

If you want to run this stack all under Docker Compose then you'd need to launch the shared services (RabbitMQ) in a single Docker Compose file, and then in the per-service Docker Compose files, refer to that other file's network as an external network.  I'd recommend just reusing your Kubernetes deployment system instead of trying to separately construct this.